# Category 'pad_counts' &  'parent' conflict

Tags: wp-query, categories

Below is the current loop I have setup:

```
    <?php
        //start products category loop
        $args = array(
            'hide_empty'  => 0,  
            'parent'      => 0,
            'orderby'     => 'name',
            'order'       => 'ASC',
            'taxonomy'    => 'profile_categories',
            'pad_counts'  => 1
        );

        $categories = get_categories($args);
        foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
            <?php 
            // setup the category ID
            $cat_id = $category->term_id;
            // Get category name
            $cat_name = $category->name;
            // Get category count
            $cat_count = $category->count;

            //get the category url
            $cat_url = get_term_link( $category->slug, 'profile_categories' );

            echo "<h2>";
            echo $cat_name;
            $subcat_args = array(
                'hide_empty'  => 0,  
                'orderby'     => 'name',
                'child_of'    => $cat_id,
                'order'       => 'ASC',
                'taxonomy'    => 'profile_categories',
                'pad_counts'  => 1
            );
            $subcategories = get_categories($subcat_args);
            $subcat_count = count($subcategories);
            if ($subcat_count > 0) { echo ' ('.$subcat_count.' Subcategories)'; }
            echo "</h2>";

            echo '<a href="';
            echo $cat_url;
            echo '">';
            echo __('View all','roots');
            echo "</a>";

            // Get posts belonging to current category
            $post_args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'post_type' => 'moulding_profiles',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'profile_categories',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'parent' => 0,
                        'terms' => $cat_id
                    )
                )
            );
            $posts_query = new WP_Query($post_args);
            if ($posts_query->have_posts() ) {
                echo '<ul>';
                    while ($posts_query->have_posts()) : $posts_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> -> Width: <?php the_field('mp_profile_dimensions_width',get_the_ID()); ?> Height: <?php the_field('mp_profile_dimensions_height',get_the_ID()); ?></li>
                    <?php endwhile; 
                echo '</ul>';
            } // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category
            wp_reset_query(); // reset the query ?>
        <?php } // done the foreach statement ?>
```

What this does is list categories within a taxonomy called `profile_categories`, and then lists `4` items that are within each category. The category argument is using `parent => 0` so that only top-level categories are shown. What I'd like to do is also use `pad_counts => 1` to grab the count of not only the category, but all subcategories within that. So - if I'm thinking of this correctly, `parents` conflicts with `pad_counts`. I've looked through the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) about this and am stuck in the mud on if this is even possible - or if I'm that clueless and am missing something obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Update**: Using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories as a reference, when `parent` is set to `0` (to only show top-level categories), the `$category->count` and `$category->category_count` does not include the count of the sub-categories - still thinking this is a bug unless someone knows of a workaround.

Comment: Could this possibly be a bug? http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13176

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is potentially a bug* - but it doesn't seem like it is the same one you have linked to. The problem lies in the `get_terms` function. Specifically here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1397

The array of terms (which when `parent=0`, are are just the top level terms) gets passed to `_pad_term_counts` which says:

> Add count of children to parent count.
>
> Recalculates term counts by including items from child terms. **Assumes all
>   relevant children are already in the $terms argument**

So the `_pad_term_counts` function does its job properly, but its only ever given the top level terms and so only counts the posts in those terms, and not any child terms.

A work-around (this is not particular efficient), is to get all categories and then filter out all but the top level ones. Then has far as `get_categories` (and so `get_terms`) is concerned - you are after all terms and so all get counted:

```
    //The args. Don't set parent
    $args = array(
        'hide_empty'  => 0,  
        'orderby'     => 'name',
        'order'       => 'ASC',
        'taxonomy'    => 'category',
        'pad_counts'  => 1
    );

    //I'll leave it to you to check for error objects etc.
    $categories = get_categories($args));
    $categories = wp_list_filter($categories,array('parent'=>0));
```

** Or maybe not: it is simply excluding the count of terms which do not match the criteria.*

Comment: Awesome! Never knew about `wp_list_filter()` before. While not the most efficient, saves my sanity nonetheless. I can't give you the bounty as of yet (says I have to wait a little longer) but I'll jump back on shortly to try. Thanks again!

Comment: Great Answer. But a small code typo error on line get_categories($args)); It has an extra closing bracket. I tried to edit but it is a single line and the system doesn't let me do that. Thanks